# First random number is alway the same

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to write a simple program. I heard in C++ that there are existing functions that are better than `rand()` (to make random numbers). I am talking about classes from `#include <random>`. My program goal is to make random numbers.

This is my code:

```cpp
int randomSpawn()
{    
    unsigned seed = time(NULL);
    std::default_random_engine rng(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1, LENGHT);
    
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::cout << d(rng) << std::endl;
    std::cout << rand() % LENGHT << std::endl;

    return rand() % LENGHT;
}
```

The problem is that the first value is always the same - `17`. `LENGTH` is equal to 30.

So, the **oldest version making random number is working** - because it displays a random number, but the **new version doesn't work** because it always displays 17.

I tried to move the seed definition to another part of code, but it didn't help.

Comment: It'll be the same every time `time()` returns the same number which usually happens every time you call it during the same second.

Comment: They are both broken. You are only supposed to initialize/seed the RNG _once_ (e.g. at the beginning of `main`), not every time you call the function.

Comment: Side note: Prefer to use `std::random_device` as the seed to using time. Anyone who knows the current time knows the seed, and if they also know the engine's algorithm, they know the numbers that will be generated. Things are about as random as Candy Land at that point, the sequence 100% predetermined.

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` is a better seed than `time(NULL)`  because at least the types are compatible.  `unsigned` and `time_t` aren't (necessarily) the same size.

Comment: What @user4581301 mentioned: `std::default_random_engine rng(std::random_device{}());`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. `random device` is working :)

Comment: @Michael Great, but remember to only initialize your PRNG _once_ during the whole program run. Some PRNGs takes a _long_ time to initialize so you don't want to do that for no good reason.

Comment: Cool question.  Super minor nit: when I copied your code to test it, i happened to notice that LENGHT is misspelled

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You mix two standard random number libraries, an old one with `srand` and `rand` and the new one, with  `std::uniform_int_distribution` and `std::default_random_engine`. Don't use the old library. While its implementation most likely has improved over time, computer science has progressed since it was introduced to the C language.

   So, here's the first fix:

```cpp
#include <random>

int randomSpawn()
{
    const int LENGHT = 30;
    unsigned seed = time(NULL);
    std::default_random_engine rng(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1, LENGHT);

    return d(rng);
}
```

2. Now the second error: you create & initialize a new random number generator each time you call `randomSpawn`. This is plain wrong. Usually, you use only one random number generator per program (or thread), and if you use more, you take great care not to mix them. And you always initialize it/them once. The reason is that random number generators are meant to be fast, so they produce deterministic sequences that *look* to be random but actually are not. The numbers in these sequences are so uncorrelated, that most users are okay with their being only pseudo-random. So lets move the generator out of the function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int randomSpawn(std::default_random_engine & rng)
{
    const int LENGHT = 30;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1, LENGHT);
    return d(rng);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned seed = time(NULL);
    std::default_random_engine rng(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       std::cout << randomSpawn(rng) << "\n";
}
```

Alas! This still produces the same number in the sequence! First run:

```
19
23
2
8
24
13
17
22
19
28
```

Next run:

```cpp
19
29
11
6
17
12
13
26
25
12
```

4. The code seems to work, but the first "random" number is always 19 on my machine and 17 on yours. Actually, I guess it's not the machine that matters, but the initializer, that is, `time(NULL)`, which actually, in modern C++, should be spelled  `time(nullptr)`. Each time you call this function, you receive the number of seconds that have passed since the so called Epoch. If you test a program manually, this function returns huge values that differ from each other by a small integer corresponding to a small number of seconds between successive program tests.

   People have used `time(nullptr)` for decades and their programs have run superbly. So this piece of code is not an error. The error is in using random number generators without the knowledge of how they're constructed internally. What matters is that `default_random_engine` is **implementation defined**. In my system, it resolves to `std::minstd_rand0`, which was developed as long time ago as 1969 and most likely is included in the standard C++ library only for compatibility reasons. It belongs to a class of linear congruential random number generators and its "randomness" sometimes is questionable, something that you've just seen yourself. To see how "not-random" the first number produced by this generator is, jut run this code:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     std::default_random_engine de (i + 1'000'000);
     std::cout << de() << "\n";
}
```

On my machine I get:

```
1774614471
1774631278
1774648085
1774664892
1774681699
```

that is numbers that are very close to each other.

5. So let's use something better:

```cpp
int randomSpawn(std::mt19937 & rng)
{
    const int LENGHT = 30;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1, LENGHT);
    return d(rng);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned seed = time(nullptr);
    std::mt19937 rng(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       std::cout << randomSpawn(rng) << "\n";
}
```

Here I use explicitly the golden standard in random number generators (not only in C++): a generator from the Mersenne Twister family of random number generators. As you can test it, now already the first call to the generator produces a "random" number.

If you want to be sure that the first number is "really" random, you can "warm up" the generator:

```cpp
    unsigned seed = time(nullptr);
    std::mt19937 rng(seed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // warm up 10 times to decorelate with seed 
        rng();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       std::cout << randomSpawn(rng) << "\n";
```

Alternatively, you can use a different method of the seed initialization:

```cpp
    std::random_device rd;
    unsigned seed = rd();   // produces a really "random" number
    std::mt19937 rng(seed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       std::cout << randomSpawn(rng) << "\n";
```

Comment: Good answer. One minor correction though: *Each time you call this function, you receive the number of seconds that have passed since the so called Epoch.* Technically no. The period is unspecified, but I've worked on a lot of different systems, some of them pretty weird, over decades and never seen `time` return anything other than seconds. In my opinion you can take one second as being the word of the Prophet even if not the literal word of God.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty tricky.  `std::default_random_engine` is just guaranteed to produce pseudo-random values based on the seed you pass in.  There's no guarantee that different seeds will result in different values.  [CPlusPlus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/) says,

> It is the library implemention's selection of a generator that provides at least acceptable engine behavior for relatively casual, inexpert, and/or lightweight use

While this isn't a quote from the standard, it goes to show that `default_random_engine` is meant to be convenient rather than secure or reliably "random" in any sort of technical way.

Because of this flexibility, we can only discuss the behavior of different implementations on different machines.  We cannot say anything about this code in general across different machines/compliers/stdlib versions/etc.

On my machine, `std::default_random_engine rng(time(0))` produces the same initial value at different times -- this is the same behavior that you see on your machine in the question.  Note that most of the bits in `time(0)` are the same even at different times.  Only the low bits change.  `std::default_random_engine rng(time(0) << 10)` produces different values each time.  This suggests that `default_random_engine` is just using some of the higher bits as a seed (at least for the first number).

The example code on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random recommends using `std::random_device` rather than `time(0)` as a seed. This will give truly random bits as a seed rather than just some different low bits.  On my machine, this makes the first number different each time.